# Installing error: Unkown failure (android emulator)

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

so ive been working on this app for a proyect, and my emulators have been working fine, up until earlier today, its been 6 hours or so trying to fix this and there is no way to fix it.
Ived erased eclipse and reinstalled it, reinstall android sdk,adt. everything and i keep getting the same messege when trying to run my android application.

```
[2014-03-18 03:02:56 - Contact_List] Android Launch!
[2014-03-18 03:02:56 - Contact_List] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-18 03:02:56 - Contact_List] Performing com.example.contact_list.MainActivity   activity launch
[2014-03-18 03:02:56 - Contact_List] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'tester'
[2014-03-18 03:02:56 - Contact_List] Uploading Contact_List.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-18 03:02:56 - Contact_List] Installing Contact_List.apk...
[2014-03-18 03:02:59 - Contact_List] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-03-18 03:02:59 - Contact_List] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-03-18 03:02:59 - Contact_List] Launch canceled!
```

on top of that everytime I open the AVD on eclipse it wont let me create a virtual device, I have to go straight to the adt folder and open the AVD.exe.

any way to fix this? is it the new android adt version 22.6?
because it all happend after my eclipse did some updates.
I also tried reverting the updates and it didnt work.

Comment: Its new known bug, please read this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

Answer (score 3):

ADT version 22.6.3 java compiler 1.7 I had same problem. But I solved it. In my case 
`use same device for future launches`  was checked. which try to run on previous emulator. So
Go To `Run Configuration->Target->uncheck use same device for future launches` if you want `check Always prompt to pick device` so that you get choice.

here is console where both problem and solution is here

```
[2014-06-08 16:51:14 - IMS_RMS] ------------------------------
[2014-06-08 16:51:15 - IMS_RMS] Android Launch!
[2014-06-08 16:51:15 - IMS_RMS] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-08 16:51:15 - IMS_RMS] Performing com.example.ims_rms.Splash activity launch
[2014-06-08 16:51:18 - IMS_RMS] Uploading IMS_RMS.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-08 16:51:20 - IMS_RMS] Installing IMS_RMS.apk...
[2014-06-08 16:51:23 - IMS_RMS] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-06-08 16:51:23 - IMS_RMS] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-06-08 16:51:24 - IMS_RMS] Launch canceled!
[2014-06-08 16:53:49 - IMS_RMS] ------------------------------
[2014-06-08 16:53:49 - IMS_RMS] Android Launch!
[2014-06-08 16:53:49 - IMS_RMS] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-08 16:53:49 - IMS_RMS] Performing com.example.ims_rms.Splash activity launch
[2014-06-08 16:53:59 - IMS_RMS] Launch canceled!
[2014-06-08 17:01:28 - IMS_RMS] ------------------------------
[2014-06-08 17:01:28 - IMS_RMS] Android Launch!
[2014-06-08 17:01:28 - IMS_RMS] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-08 17:01:29 - IMS_RMS] Performing com.example.ims_rms.Splash activity launch
[2014-06-08 17:01:44 - IMS_RMS] Uploading IMS_RMS.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2014-06-08 17:01:48 - IMS_RMS] Installing IMS_RMS.apk...
[2014-06-08 17:02:35 - IMS_RMS] Success!
[2014-06-08 17:02:41 - IMS_RMS] Starting activity com.example.ims_rms.Splash on device emulator-5556
```

Answer (score 0):

goto Run as-> run configure->target
at the end find a tag "use the same device for future launches"
remove the tick of check box.
Again run application

Answer (score 0):

If You Running In Eclipse, Check Your Settings.

Run Configurations - Common - Select File In Standard Input And Output - Click

Workspace And Choose Your Project.

And Just Click Run.